# Not Repeating Words in Swift when clicking button - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I am learning how to program in Kotlin on my own and for a small project, I'm trying to build an app that randomizes fruits without repeating the fruit.

My Question for you is: 
How can I not repeat the array when I click on the button in Kotlin? I'm trying to generate fruits without them repeating. Can I sort the string that way it runs through all the fruits one by one? It doesn't have to be randomized. I just want each word to show only once when I click the button and show the last array "There aren't any fruit options left"

I tried to randomize the string but that repeats the fruits. I just want it to go one by one. When I press the button on my screen the output on the image label should give me each fruit one at a time.

ie. Button pressed" Output: "Apple"

button pressed again Output: "Banana"

and so on until the last string shows "There aren't any fruit options left"

Previous Fruit Button Question: Do you know how I can go back to the previous array? 
For example if I clicked the buttons and Apple, Banana, Orange showed but I wanted to go back to see banana. How would I do that?

```
class Fruits : AppCompatActivity() {

private val Fruit = arrayListOf("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Dried Managos","Grapes")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fruit)

        nextQuestion1.setOnClickListener {
            val random = Random ()
            val randomProgram = random.nextInt(Fruit.count())

            FruitText.text = Fruit[randomProgram]
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin provides excellent `Collections` api, and one such option is `shuffle` which shuffles the given collection. You do not need to generate random numbers and then keep track of what number has already been generated. Simply use the following:

```
class Fruits : AppCompatActivity() {

private val Fruit = arrayListOf("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Dried Managos","Grapes")

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fruit)

    nextQuestion1.setOnClickListener {
        Fruit.shuffle()
        FruitText.text = fruit[(0..Fruit.size)Random()]
    }
}
```

NOTE: `Collections` api is packaged in Kotlin standard library and not the language.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to go back to the previous fruit? How can I show last string shows "There aren't any fruit options left"

Comment: How would I get the Collections api?

Comment: If you are using Kotlin Standard Library then they comes shipped with it.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. thank you.